# Java + Selenium + Frame :How to interact on element inside frame?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, form

**Problem -**

I've been trying to find the correct xpath for a element. I couldn't get the element in correct manner.

**Observation -**

I observed, It may be due to the element is located inside or under the frame component. Can anyone help me to interact with the element which is located under frame?

**Question - How to interact on element inside frame?**

Below I'm sharing html code, for better understanding.

```
<div class="login-block last">
    <form name="frm" action="authenticatorProcess.cgi" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)">
    <form name="frm" action="authenticatorProcess.cgi" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)">
    <table width="290" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <th align="right">
        <td align="left">
        <input id="rutClient" name="rutClient" size="15" onchange="Rut(document.frm.rutClient.value)" onblur="Rut(document.frm.rutClient.value)" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

<div class="login-block last">
<form name="frm" action="authenticatorProcess.cgi" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)">
<table width="290" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <th align="right">
        <td align="left">
    <input id="rutClient" name="rutClient" size="15" onchange="Rut(document.frm.rutClient.value)" onblur="Rut(document.frm.rutClient.value)" type="text">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried with the following

```
by.xpath(//form[@name='frm']//input[@type='text'])//*[@id='rutClient']
//html/body/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/input/by.id("rutClient")
```

Comment: What does "elementToBeSelected" mean in this context?  I would have thought only checkboxes etc. could be selected, not text elements.

Comment: If your element has id, why you insist on locating it by XPATH? Id > name > css > link text, I avoid XPATH like a plague.

Comment: i tried with the by.id but element is not found

Comment: Voting to Reopen!

Answer (score 2):

Well said Peter. Totally Agree for ID > Name > CSS > LinkText

@josekimet -

- First ensure that element you are looking to perform action is visible

  `your_element.isDisplayed();`
- If not visible then you need to add implicit wait until that element get visible on page
- After that using ID, I guess you will able to interact with element
- Modified: If you are interacting element which is in frame. You need to switch to that frame
- Once you switch to targeted frame then only all the elements will be accessible with locators like id/name/css/xpath

  `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('frame_id'));`
- Now you will be able to find element using 'id'

  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='element_id']"));`

Comment: i found that the item is inside a frame

Comment: but i couldn't get the by id.. how i tell the driver to look into the frame?

Comment: you can use xpath using more than one locator. ex - driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='element_id' and @name='actual_parameter_value']")); you can use name/class/css/type

Comment: updated my answer - it should work now. Pls check